# Reading Excel from URL with memory stream

Tags: c#, excel, azure, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I am uploading an excel file to Azure,I am following [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-/) url.
Now I have to read this excel file with its URL(I don't want to download it).
I am doing this

```
var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("url_of_excel_in_Azure") as HttpWebRequest;
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

using (var webResponseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    webResponseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
    {
        var value = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First().Cells[1, 1].Value;

    }
}
```

I have a specific format for excel ie it will have only 4 columns,but multiple rows, from the above code I can access first row's first column value,How can I apply loop on these Cells to read all rows in 4 columns.
If I write

```
  excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First().Cells.Count()
```

It's giving  me the count of all columns including which are blank.

I can skip this upload functionality as I need to just create  DataTable from the posted file, If someone can suggest how can I create datatable from posted file without uploading it,that will be good too.
This is the format of my Excel
[image: excel]

Answer (score 0):

Rewind stream with memoryStream.Position =0;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to read the content of all rows and throw them into a data table.

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

int iRowCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int iColCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

Excel.Range range;

for (int iRow = 2; iRow <= iRowCount; iRow++) {
    for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= iColCount; iCol++)
        range = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRow, iCol];

        string content = range.Text.ToString();
}
```